# Unable to run Linphone-android source code on actual device

Tags: android, logcat

I have downloaded the Linphone-android source code using git clone. When I imported the source codes into eclipse, there were no errors found. I then tried to run the app on the actual device, however, the app was unable to load and it crashed. Here is the logcat of the errors. May I know how to resolve this issue? And what is causing this issue?

```
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactory.instance(LinphoneCoreFactory.java:43)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:460)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:271)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:142)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2208)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1102)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone: findLibrary returned null
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.<clinit>(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:59)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     ... 18 more
```

Thanks all in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you downloaded the necessary native libraries, generate the .so files, and include it in your project?

Comment: @Kai Are those native libraries included in the git clone? If so, yes. Sorry, but may I know how to generate the .so files and include them in my project? I am kinda new to this. I really need help and guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error as mentioned above.

- git clone source code of linphone-android using Ubuntu 11.10
- install autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize, pkgconfig (as mentioned in README file) using terminal in Ubuntu
- ./prepare_sources.sh in project root folder
- build project using Android NDK