# Unable to run Linphone-android source code on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android, linphone

Im trying to run linphone source code in Windows 7, i git cloned the linphone source. there were no error... but when i try to run it on my Galaxy S it gives crashes the app, then i search it on Google and found the same crash reported,

[Unable to run Linphone-android source code on actual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068619/unable-to-run-linphone-android-source-code-on-actual-device)
`04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactory.instance(LinphoneCoreFactory.java:43)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:460)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:271)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:142)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2208)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1102)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone: findLibrary returned null
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.<clinit>(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:59)
04-09 11:19:37.332: E/AndroidRuntime(9930):     ... 18 more`

But i could not find a solution mention here.. what are the native lib which require to download?? i did not install these autotools mentioned, how can i get them... please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to build linphone android source After few days of trying on windows7(using cygwin, autotools).
But succeeded after using a MAC to build.

answer of this question has all the steps which required.
[Linphone for android is not working/missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086307/linphone-for-android-is-not-working-missing-libraries)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Android SDK and NDK

SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife
NDK: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html (native lib)

**Important**: you have to set the path in the system. 
For Win 7 -> [How to add android tools dir to windows 7 path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285670/how-to-add-android-tools-dir-to-windows-7-path)

If the path is not right you will get some errors like "Android NDK not found" ..

In the root folder from linphone you will find a readme. Follow the steps.
Maybe you have to use linux or mac. I dont know if its work on Win 7 well.

Let me know if its worked.

Greetz

Comment: Thanks for answering...i downloaded cygwin again with the autotools installed. and try to run source prepare_sources.sh in cygwing bash shell, then it shows the ./autogen.sh : No such file or directory

Comment: Don't use prepare_sources.sh - it's deprecated. Use **make**. Be sure that you the the path to sdk and ndk. With **make install** you can install the linphone app on your device, and with **make linphone-sdk** you can create the library for use.

Comment: I used **make linphone-sdk** using my cygwin shell to the path of my linphone source cloned in git repository. but it give the error of **make: No rule to make target 'linphone-sdk'. Stop.**. SDK and NDK paths are already set in Environmental Variables, what would i do??

Comment: Did you run only **make** first?

Comment: i did that too... cursor blinks for few seconds and it gives me this error,                                                         **--/bin/sh: line 1: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
--iLBC prepare stage failed 
--Makefile:18: recipe for target 'prepare-ilbc' failed
--make:  [prepare-ilbc] Error 1**

Comment: That looks like that autogen isn't installed. Sry, i have no experience with Windows and Cygwin. Please check that the Packages from the top of the README are installed.